# Compare 2 month name strings in c language eg, feb>jan

Tags: c, string, enums, billing, monthcalendar

I need to program a simple bill payment with month program. There would be let's say inputs such as,

Apr May

The first one is the month where I'm supposed to pay the bill, and the second one is the month where I paid the bill. Each month that I do not follow the due month of paying, an interest would be added in the original bill.

Let's say,

500.00 0.10

The first float is the original bill and the second one is the interest.
On the other hand, if you pay the bill on the same month, there would no interest. You just put the original bill as is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void sum(float ,float );
void sum1(float,float);

int main()
{
    char fmonth[10];                       
    char smonth[10];
    double original, interest,bill,bill2;
  
    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%s %s %lf %lf ",&fmonth,&smonth,&original,&interest);
 
    if(strcmp(fmonth,"Jan")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Feb")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Feb")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Mar")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Mar")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Apr")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Apr")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"May")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"May")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Jun")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Jun")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Aug")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Aug")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Sep")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Sep")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Oct")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Oct")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Nov")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Nov")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Dec")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,"Dec")==0 && strcmp(smonth,"Jan")==0)
    {  
         sum(original,interest);
    }
    else if(strcmp(fmonth,smonth)==0)
    {  
         sum1(original,interest);
    }
 
    
}
void sum(float original,float interest)
{
    double a,b;
    a=original*interest;
    b=a+original;
    printf("%.2lf",b);
}
void sum1(float original,float interest)
{
    printf("%.2lf",original);
}
```

Of course, there would be cases that the `fmonth`&& `smonth` is not just one month gap right? E.g

`Jan Dec`

he is supposed to pay at `jan` but he paid in `dec`. The interest needs to be equivalent to how months did the customer paid the bill away from the due month.

i can't just manually predict all the outcomes right? there must be away to shorten it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve them, for example by including a [mcve] of your own attempt together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: This is why [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) exists (`YYYY-MM-DD`) and why you should use it. Super easy sorting.

Comment: but it's the requirement for my homework :(

Comment: @randomCprogrammer Well, then show the code you've tried and explain where you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

To compare months, you must convert the month name to its corresponding number and compare these numbers.  You can use a perfect hash for this: a simple function that computes a different number for all valid values. Below is an example that works for ASCII representations on both upper and lower case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int month_number(const char *a) {
#define HASH(a,b,c)  (((b) + (c)) & 31)
    switch (HASH(a[0], a[1], a[2])) {
    case HASH('j','a','n'): return 1;
    case HASH('f','e','b'): return 2;
    case HASH('m','a','r'): return 3;
    case HASH('a','p','r'): return 4;
    case HASH('m','a','y'): return 5;
    case HASH('j','u','n'): return 6;
    case HASH('j','u','l'): return 7;
    case HASH('a','u','g'): return 8;
    case HASH('s','e','p'): return 9;
    case HASH('o','c','t'): return 10;
    case HASH('n','o','v'): return 11;
    case HASH('d','e','c'): return 12;
    default: return 0;
    }
}

int compare_months(const char *a, const char *b) {
    int ma = month_number(a);
    int mb = month_number(b);
    return (ma > mb) - (ma < mb);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char fmonth[10], smonth[10];
    double original, rate, interest;
  
    printf("Enter start and end month, capital and interest rate: ");
    if (scanf("%9s %9s %lf %lf", fmonth, smonth, &original, &rate) == 4) {
        int fmon = month_number(fmonth);
        int smon = month_number(smonth);

        if (fmon == 0 || smon == 0) {
            printf("invalid month\n");
        } else {
            if (smon <= fmon)
                smon += 12;
            // compute interest, assuming reimbursement on the same day of the month
            interest = round((double)(smon - fmon) * rate / 12.0) / 100.0;
            printf("Result: %.2f\n", original + interest);
        }
    } else {
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: absolutely. I added a comment about this approach, aka as perfect hashing, which is this case works in a case insensitive way for English month names using the ASCII charset.

Answer (score 1):

An easy workaround would be mapping each month to its corresponding *number* (e.g. March->3 and then, instead of comparing Strings, you can *compare* those *values*.